# How do you update an object within an observable array, without re-querying the server?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I'm experimenting with creating a store for managing my data, and then consuming that store in my components. App is built with Ionic2 and Angular2.

### UPDATE

Here's a link to how I modeled my data store https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services

The trouble I'm having is **updating** objects in an observable.

Here's the Store

```
export class MessageService {
    messages$: Observable<Message[]>;
    update() {
        //...code to make http call and set `this.messages$`
    }
    setMessageFlag(msg: Message) {
        //post to server, nothing more, nothing returned
    }
}
```

Now my component injects this service

```
export class Inbox OnInit {
    messages$: Observable<Messages[]>

    constructor(private $messageService: MessageService) {
        this.messages$ = this.$messageService.messages$;
    }

    flagMessage(msg: Message) {
        msg.isNew = !msg.isNew;
        this.$messageService.setMessageFlag(msg); //makes a http call to set the message flag
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.$messageService.update();
    }
}
```

Then my template consumes the observable using the `async` pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let message of messages$ | async">
    <h2 [ngClass]="{'is-read': message.isNew}">{{message.title}}</h2>
    <button (click)="flag(message)">{{message.isNew ? 'Mark as read' : 'Mark as unread'}}</button>
</div>
```

Now for the part I'm confused with.

```
flagMessage(msg: Message) {
    msg.isNew = !msg.isNew;
    this.$messageService.setMessageFlag(msg);
}
```

When the button is clicked, and `flagMessage(message)` method is called, it sets the `msg.isNew`, and makes the http call to the server. I see the `is-new` class applied to the `<h2>`, but then it quickly reverts back to its **original** value.

I don't want to make a call to fetch all the messages from the server again. That seems inefficient. I'm thinking that the Observable is returning a copy, but I'm not sure.

It's been quite a learning curve for me lately. I've jumped onto Angular2, Typescript2, Rxjs, and Ionic2, all within the last month so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without code of the update method it's hard to tell

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I'll add the code and update.

Comment: @AlexanderCiesielski I added a link to the article I modeled my data service after. I'm at work, so everything I've put down is from memory. I'll update with my code once I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I think ideal for this situation is [`ReplaySubject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html) that can remember the last value emited and reemit it to all Observers that subscribe after the value was first emited.

```
import {Observable, ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';

var results = new ReplaySubject(1);

// Simulate HTTP request
Observable.create(subscriber => {
  console.log('Observable.create');
  var data = 'response data';
  results.next(data);
}).subscribe();

results.subscribe(r => console.log(r));
results.subscribe(r => console.log(r));
results.subscribe(r => console.log(r));

// prints to console:
// Observable.create
// response data
// response data
// response data
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/DOPsPlMxh06g1lWoJllQ

Even though the three Observers subscribe after `"response data"` was first emitted using `results.next(data)` they all receive the same data.

As far as I understand your use case, you'll make `messages$` an instance of `ReplaySubject` because that's where you subscribe your Observers. Then logic that calls the HTTP request and calls `messages$.next(...)` can be completely independent on it. All new subscribers to `messages$` should therefore receive the last response from the server which is I think what you're going for (?).

Comment: Problem with this is that when you swap out for a real `http` data source you will complete the `ReplaySubject` and not be able to receive any more data on it.

Comment: @paulpdaniels Why, would you complete the `ReplaySubject`? `results` is fully under your control and it's independent on any HTTP requests.

Comment: You said you were mocking `http` requests if you instead were to do `http.get().subscribe(results)` the `http` would complete the `ReplaySubject`

Comment: I'm not subscribing `results` to anything in this example... I'm not even mentioning such thing anywhere...

Comment: My point was more about that that *when* one does switch out the simulated endpoint for real data, they will likely be using the `$http` service not `Observable.create`, hence they will need to subscribe to it. But fair enough if that wasn't your implication.